# JUnit Max Equivalent Tool for Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, unit-testing

I have been trying to find a tool similar to [JUnit Max](http://www.junitmax.com/junitmax/subscribe.html) for Visual Studio.

Preferably, the tool would work with Visual Studio 2008 Professional and NUnit.

For those who are apparently unable to click through to the JUnit Max site, here is the description.

> JUnit Max is a continuous testing plug-in for Eclipse that helps programmers stay focused on coding by running tests intelligently and reporting results unobtrusively. Every time you save a Java file, Max runs your tests and reports errors in the same format as compile errors.
>
> Max fails fast, running the tests most likely to fail first. You only have to pay close attention to test results for a second (literally) before getting back to coding, even if you have a long-running test suite

Try thinking of it like this...

Visual Studio detects and highlights syntax errors.
I would like to see unit-test errors highlighted in the IDE just like syntax errors.

Comment: What kind of hardware do you need for a tool like that?

Comment: I don't think it would take anything special. The tool prioritizes tests so that the ones most likely to fail are ran first. That way you don't really have to wait for the whole suite to run before you get back to coding.

Comment: I really wish this did exist. Unfortunately, the .net community tends to be a few years behind everyone else with this sort of thing. It will come eventually, but isn't here yet.

Comment: Yeah, it really would be awesome, wouldn't it? I would try to create this tool myself if I had enough motivation and free time.

Comment: I read through the answers on this post and I dont understand how people could miss the point of this answer by SO MUCH? LOL. How can they equate JUnit Max with Continuous Integration servers? =p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is one!

Have a look at [NCrunch](http://www.ncrunch.net/). It runs your tests in the background and even updates coverage information while you're typing.

They have a screen cast on their web page. Currently it is in beta and free; but I guess, they'll charge for it soon. I'm quite sure it will be worth the money, though.

**NCrunch**
(vendor information!)

> NCrunch is an automated parallel continuous testing tool for Visual Studio .NET. It intelligently takes responsibility for running automated tests so that you don't have to, and it gives you a huge amount of useful information about your tests (such as code coverage) inline in your IDE while you work.

Comment: I also submitted a feature request for ReSharper. It should be quite easy for them to implement: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-275674

Answer (score 5):

It's not quite a plugin solution, but the NUnit GUI runner can do what you're after. You can change the settings so that it re-runs the last test run whenever your test assembly is modified. Hence when you re-compile all your tests will be run again (assuming your last test run ran every test of course).

You may already have this setup if you're already using NUnit, but you can also add the GUI runner to Visual Studio as an external tool, so that you can open it from within Visual Studio, with your test assembly already loaded. Again, this integration can be instantiated from within the GUI runner's settings dialog.

More information is available on the NUnit site, I'd link it but I'm too new a user!

**EDIT:** Another solution would be to add a post build event to your project, passing your test assembly to the NUnit runner. As described [here](http://www.csharptocsharp.com/visual-studio-automate-unit-testing). I appreciate that this still doesn't address the test prioritization aspect, though.

Comment: Thanks, BenA. That's an almost-solution, but the IDE integration and test-prioritization make the whole process a lot smoother.

Answer (score 3):

i've been looking for the same thing ever since seeing junitmax run on eclipse, as far as i can tell there is nothing like it for the .net platform yet :(

the best available solution seems to be 'run tests on compile'. there's an interesting blog post about ['Extreme continuous integration'](http://www.chrisedwards.dreamhosters.com/blog/2010/06/13/extreme-continuous-integration-a-personal-ci-build-for-visual-studio-part-1/). you can at least run the tests on a seperate machine this way.

also keep an eye out for [mighty moose](http://www.continuoustests.com/)

some blog posts about it [here](http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/design-architecture/mighty-moose) and [here](http://abdullin.com/journal/2010/11/11/mighty-moose-smart-continuous-unit-tests-for-net-and-mono.html) it has a more official name but i cant remember what it is right now.

Comment: That's a helpful link. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

there are a number of projects on this:

http://ox.no/software/continuoustesting

http://quicktest.codeplex.com/

and others :)

Comment: Thanks, those look helpful. I think QuickTest.NET comes the closest to JUnit Max-like behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Team City will let you run personal builds, so it will not check in the broken code. Only after all unit tests pass will it check in the code. Is that what you are after?

Comment: Not exactly, no. Check out the JUnit Max slideshow for details.

Comment: I looked at the first page and slide shows and I think that Team City can do that too with Risk Test Reordering. Take a look at http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/TCD4/Risk+Tests+Reordering+in+Custom+Test+Runner.

Comment: @epitka - That's pretty cool. Does Team City also highlight the failing lines in the IDE? I've downloaded Team City, but I haven't installed or configured it yet.

Comment: epitka - I installed TeamCity and I don't see any "personal builds" feature. Aside from that, I could not get it to work on my system. I am not able to run the build agent service under my user account, I have to run it as SYSTEM. That's a problem for the VCS I'm required to use, though. :(

Comment: Personal build is accessed through TeamCity>Remote Run in VS2008, but you have to be able to log into your server first.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to automatically check out your code from the repository, compile it, run all unit test and send a report via email to all project members? Right?

If so, you are searching for the wrong term. You are looking for "continious integration".

Try products like:
[CruiseControl.NET](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Welcome+to+CruiseControl.NET) or [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/index.html).

Comment: That is not what I'm looking for. Please examine the link I posted for an example of continuous unit testing. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: For me there is no difference between running the test on a dedicated server (on check in) or your lokal computer (on saving)...except the performance you need when compiling the programm on every file save.

Comment: There are several differences. The biggest one for me is the IDE integration. Another useful difference is that you don't check in broken code then discover that the test fails. You discover that the test fails as soon as you recompile. And the "most important" tests run first so you don't have to wait for the entire test run. Again, I urge you to please follow the link in my question to see how JUnit Max provides continuous unit testing.

Comment: TeamCity gives you IDE integration

Answer (score 0):

There's no Visual Studio equivalent that I'm aware of, but if you're an IntelliJ user you can use [Infinitest](http://infinitest.org). Infinitest is also free, which is a nice perk.

Answer (score -2):

Have you looked at [CruiseControl](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/)

I haven't used it personally but another dev team at my old job used it for continuous integration/Continuous builds on their project.

Theres a good article on CodeProject re: [Continuous Integration with CruiseControl.net](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/testing/ContinuousIntegration.aspx) which covers NUnit Testing & CHM Documentation Builds as well

Comment: I have heard good things about CruiseControl as well, but I'm not looking for continuous integration, I'm looking for continuous unit testing. Thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score -2):

If I understand correctly, your looking for something like ReSharper. ReSharper has a very nice, integrated unit test runner that lets you run full suites or individual tests. It has a nice test result browser, which can make it very easy to jump strait to code that is causing exceptions and whatnot. ReSharper isn't free, but in addition to integrated unit testing, it offers a TON of other usability features and improvements that integrate with Visual Studio.

If TestDriven.NET isn't good enough, ReSharper will definitely serve your needs.

Comment: he is not looking for an IDE testrunner, he is looking for an integrated continious tester

Answer (score -2):

i think you are searching for [MSBuild with NUnit](http://www.zorched.net/2006/11/28/msbuild-with-nunit/),